# How to highlight several countries using Google Chart API by country code?

Tags: google-visualization

I have a simple request that selects a country on a map by code (e.g. FR for France) in Google chart:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?&cht=t&chs=440x220&chtm=europe&chco=f5f5f5,edf0d4,6c9642,13390a&chld=FR&chd=s:FR

I know that this can be extended to selecting several countries but I cannot construct a proper request. Can someone give an example of how to do it (e.g. highlighting FR and IT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the syntax more or less:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?&cht=t&chs=440x220&chtm=europe&chco=f5f5f5,edf0d4,6c9642,13390a&chld=FR|IT|CZ|DE&chd=s:afhx

so one should use "|" to separate countries and then provide enough color by using alphanumeric encoding (1 char per country)